# Performance issues between customtkinter and Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, tkinter, customtkinter

I made an desktop app with customtkinter that extract txt file into excel. The app had a file selector button and extract button. The file selector will open the txt file and read the table in the txt file and the extract button will make some data manipulation. I had some issues regarding performance which when the user clicked the button, the app will be frozen while the pandas extracting/ make data manipulation. I also already used the other thread to make the data extraction.

Here the button code to open file:
`btn = ctk.CTkButton(master=frame, text='Browse', width=100, command=lambda: Thread(target=self.__select_file).start())`

The open file event handler basically will let user choose the file and check table in txt file which than return result object. The checkbox will be enabled/disabled based on result object to be extracted. Here the code:

```
def __select_file(self):
    __file_types = [
      ('Listing file', ['*psilst*', '*saclst*, *pstlst*', '*psilst', '*saclst', '*pstlst', '*psilst', 'psilst*', 'saclst*', 'pstlst*', 'saclst', 'pstlst']),
      ('All file', '*.*')
    ]
    self.__reset_checkbox_state()
    file = ctk.filedialog.askopenfile(title='Open listing file', initialdir='./', filetypes=__file_types)
    if file == None:
      self.__set_app_status('No file selected')
      self.__listing_file['name'].set('No file selected')
      self.__listing_file['file'] = None
      return

    filename = file.name.split('/')[-1]
    self.__listing_file['name'].set(filename)
    self.__listing_file['file'] = ReadTextFile(file) ## custom class here

    self.__set_app_status('Checking tables in listing file')
    result = None
    self.__set_submit_btn_config(state=ctk.DISABLED)
    result = check_listing_file_table(self.__listing_file['file'])

    for key in result:
      checked_table: bool = result[key]
      state = "normal" if checked_table else "disabled"
      temp_key = '_'.join(key.split('_')[1:])
      self.__set_checkbox_config(key=temp_key, state=state)

    self.__set_app_status('Finish checking tables')
    self.__set_submit_btn_config(state=ctk.NORMAL)
```

Is there any suggestion to make the app not frozen while extracting the txt file? I had use Thread but when the file is bigger, the app still be frozen.